# Show DE is closed

Tags: measure-theory

Does anyone know how to deal with the following kind of question?

[image]

Here is the definition of Dynkin System:
[image]
Also definition of intersection-closed:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F\in \mathscr{D}_E$, by definition, we have

$$F\cap E\in\mathscr{D} $$
and $E\in\mathscr{D}$.

Since $\mathscr{D}$ is a Dynkin system,  $E \setminus \big( E\cap F \big)\in \mathscr{D}$, that is,

$$F^c\cap E\in\mathscr{D} $$
thus $F^c\in\mathscr{D}_E$.

**Q.E.D.**